# Access HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR Header in Apache for Django

Tags: django, apache, http-headers, ip-address

I want to read client's IP address in Django. When I try to do so now with the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR Header, it fails.  The key is not present.

Apparently this is related to configuring my Apache server (I'm deploying with apache and mod_wsgi).  I have to configure it as a reverse proxy?  How do I do that, are there security implications?

Thanks, 
Brendan

Comment: where are you looking for that Header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these headers are available in `request.META`.  So you might try `request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Are you using Apache as a reverse proxy as well?  This doesn't seem right to me.  Usually one uses a lighter weight static server like nginx as the reverse proxy to Apache running the app server.  Nginx can send any headers you like using the `proxy_set_header` config entry.

Comment: Hi Max, I tried that META key but it threw an error.  That header isn't available.  I also looked in Firebug and it's not showing up.

Comment: It depends on whether your reverse proxy is configured properly.  Are you sure the proxy is set up correctly to send this header?

Comment: Hi Max, I don't know how to configure a reverse proxy, that was my problem. Also, I'm deploying with Apache and mod_wsgi, for the record

Comment: Why are you even using a reverse proxy?  It doesn't make sense to proxy a request to the same server that is receiving the request.  Are you just looking to get the IP?  That's request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] if not behind a proxy.

Comment: I'm not using a reverse proxy. My question was, should I use a reverse proxy.  When I looked up request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], I kept getting 127.0.0.1, which is the local host. I was running it on my local host via the django development server.  I researched online and I found articles which suggested that REMOTE_ADDR didn't work with proxies and that you had to go with FORWARDED_FOR.

Comment: Now, when I try [REMOTE_ADDR] on my production server, it works but the point still stands for proxied requests.  I'll still presumably need FORWARDED_FOR.  My question is how do I include that header in my requests via an Apache configuration

Comment: Okay, so REMOTE_ADDR is only useful for a single server configuration.  If you do decide to reverse proxy (and I'm not suggesting you do unless you have a requirement, like load balancing), you need to forward an IP header.  If you put your server online as is, it will work with the REMOTE_ADDR header.  If you want to fake it for now, look into mod_proxy or setting an environment variable in your wsgi script and reading it in the request.environ dictionary.

Comment: Ok, thanks Max.  That was a helpful series of responses.  Question answered.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mod_wsgi, but usually the client IP address is available in the REMOTE_ADDR environment variable.
If the client is accessing the website through a proxy, or if your setup includes a reverse proxy, the proxy address will be in the REMOTE_ADDR variable instead, and the proxy may copy the original client IP in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR (depending on it's configuration).

If you have a request object, you can access these environment variables like this :

```
request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

There should be no need to change your Apache configuration or configure a reverse proxy just to get the client's IP address.